# Need an Applescript to close all open mail messages

Tags: applescript

My mom is 150 years old and when using mail on her mac she clicks a message so it opens in it's own window, then instead of closing it she minimizes it to the dock. Eventually she'll have 40 open mail messages and her mac slows way down.

Does anyone have an applescript that will close all open mail messages, set to run automatically once a day?

Sorry I don't know a thing about applescript.

Answer (score 1):

Love it, can really empathise with the elderly relatives doing the most unexpected things with technology.

Give this script a try. It works for me on 10.7, may not on a later OS.

```
if application "Mail" is not running then
    return
end if

tell application "Mail"
    set message_viewer_title to the name of message viewer 1  -- we don't want to close the main window
    close (every window whose name is not message_viewer_title)
end tell
```

Note: If a new message (draft) is open that has never been saved, Mail will ask what to do.

I'll let you have a look around for a scheduling solution.

Comment: taking advantage of the object model to avoid the loop, you can also do:              


    `tell application "Mail"
     set message_viewer_title to the name of message viewer 1
     close (every window whose name is not message_viewer_title)
    end tell`